# Proving result on matrix rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Is it true that, if $A=QR$ with $Q$ unitary matrix and $R$ an upper triangular matrix, and $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, then the rank of $A$ is the same as that of $R$? And if so, how do I prove it?

Comment: What do you mean by a 'unit matrix'?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UnitMatrix.html

Comment: @lemon Well, the link provides at least three different meanings of this term, (1) the matrix of all ones, (2) the invertible matrix, (3) the identity matrix

Comment: Sorry I meant Unitary. [See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix). Let me edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\text{Rank(A)}=\dim(\text{Im}A)=\dim(Q^{-1}(\text{Im}A))=\dim(\text{Im}Q^{-1}A)=\dim(\text{Im}(R))=\text{Rank}(R).$$
Note that $Q$ is unitary and therefore an isomorphism. You are looking at QR decomposition, or a matrix representation of Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization.

Comment: So we can deduce that in general if $\mathrm{rank}(A)=r$, then for any invertible matrix $B$ we have $\mathrm{rank}(BA)=r$, right?

Comment: @MickG You're right.